# Only some functions controller work with laravel messages

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, message

I have this functions in my controller

**All functions here is working, but the "message" part is not working**

I want to show a notification (like in the screenshot below) to be displayed after the functions are executed

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $this->meoRepository->deleteDigestReport($id);
    return response()->json(["message" => __('digestReport.delete.success')]);
}

public function sendTest($id){
    $this->digestReportService->sendTest($id);
    return redirect()->route('digest-report.show', $id)
        ->with(["message" => __('digestReport.send.test')]);
}

public function startStop($id){

    $this->meoRepository->startStopMeo($id);

    if (MeoState::NOT_SENDING_REPORT){
        return redirect()->route('digest-report.index')
            ->with(["message" => __('digestReport.startStop.stopped')]);
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('digest-report.index')
            ->with(["message" => __('digestReport.startStop.started')]);
    }
}
```

none of the 3 generates response messages, however all work fine, create and edit work fine, with their respective messages

my **api.php**

```
Route::get('/digest-report/send-test/{digest_report}', 'DigestReportController@sendTest')->name('digest-report.send-test');
Route::get('/digest-report/start-stop/{digest_report}', 'DigestReportController@startStop')->name('digest-report.start-stop');
```

my **web.php**

```
 Route::resource('digest-report', 'DigestReportController', ['middleware' => ['role:superadministrator|administrator|user']]);
```

example with store function, it works, I want to do this, this is for my store function in the same controller

```
public function store(MeoRequest $request)
{
    $userId = Auth::id();
    $this->meoRepository->saveDigestReport($request, $userId);
    return redirect()->route('digest-report.index')
        ->with(["message" => __('digestReport.store.success')]);
}
```

and it works correctly

[image]

this is my index view, in the part of message notification content

```
@section('content')
    @if(Session::has('message'))
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div
                    class="alert alert-{!! Session::has('status') ? Session::get('status') : 'info' !!} alert-dismissable">
                    <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
                    {!! Session::get('message') !!}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: what do you mean they don't return response messages?

Comment: and where does that little message bar get its data from? provide some code for it

Comment: Do you have this translation strings?

Comment: clarify more about your question please, what's not working here?

Comment: @sta my functions work correctly, but I can't make the notifications messages appear in these functions, the others work fine

Comment: @AlexAlvarado sorry, I updated the post